# Undo interactive __future__ import

Tags: python

I typed `from __future__ import barry_as_FLUFL` in my interactive console and now the syntax has gone funny.  Can I reinstate Guido as BDFL without restarting Python?

Comment: @AndrewLi https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0401/

Comment: Is it OK to link to that PEP here? To quote its [copyright notice](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0401/#copyright): "[...] but don't even think about quoting, copying, modifying, or distributing it."

Comment: @das-g Lol! I didn't even see that part.

Comment: @das-g `linking <> quoting <> copying <> modifying <> distributing` ;P

Comment: `<>` is not transitive, so you probably mean `all(linking <> action for action in {quoting, copying, modifying, distributing})`.